# Will this mobile redirect code work and how do I test it?

Tags: php, css, redirect, mobile

I would like to re-direct visitors to my webpage to a mobile-specific version, based on the width of their device. I tried to do user-agent detection, but the more I learned, the more I realized how bad an idea it was. I put this code in, and the problem is that I don't know how to test if it works before putting the page live. I tried using DevTools emulator but it just shows the regular page and doesn't do the re-direct. I tried downloading the PHP file to my phone to test it, but can't open the PHP file there. Should I download an app to test PHP on the phone?  Or is there some simple way to test this that has evaded my elaborate google searches?  Does my code look ok?

```
 <link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 770px)" href="http://m.mysite.ca/" >
    <?php if (substr_count($_SERVER[‘HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING’], ‘gzip’)) ob_start(“ob_gzhandler”); else ob_start(); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .responsive {
      width: 99%;
      height: auto;  
    }
        if (window.screen.width < 770) {
       window.location = 'm.mysite.ca';
     }
    </style>
        <link href="css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. Because u wrote js code inside css. Put it into  tag

Comment: So put it into the html section and add <script>  </script> around it?

Comment: <script> 
     if (window.screen.width < 770) {
       window.location = 'm.mysite.ca';
     }
 </script>

Comment: Thanks, after I have done that, will I be able to test if it works in the emulator, or there is a better way?

Comment: Chrome has dev tools to emulate phone screens

Comment: When previewing this code, with your changes implemented, in Chrome's emulator, it only shows the desktop version.  (it should be redirecting)

Comment: Yeah it still didn't work. So I am not sure if the problem is that it's not actually working, or if the problem that the emulator isn't activating the redirect.

Comment: Update -  I went back to test useragent detection via PHP code downloaded from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/  and it works exactly as it is supposed to and performs the redirect in the emulator.  Thus perhaps I will rethink my statement that user-agent is a bad way to do this, since apparently for me, it's much simpler to get to actually work correctly.